# MySQL doesn't order by milliseconds

Tags: php, mysql

I am facing a weird issue.

MySQL does not order by milliseconds correctly.

My query is:

```
 SELECT a.quiz_id, a.time, b.images, b.prize_title FROM entries a, quiz b WHERE a.quiz_id = b.id AND a.member = 1  ORDER BY a.time ASC
```

`a.time` is the milliseconds, but I am getting this output:
[image]

How can I sort by the "fastest" entries? ORDER BY a.time doesn't work?

Edits:

This show correct list:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.quiz_id, a.time, b.images, b.prize_title FROM entries a, quiz b WHERE a.quiz_id = b.id AND a.member = 1 ORDER BY a.time ASC
```

But when I add "group by a.quiz_id" it doesn't show the right entries?

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.quiz_id, a.time, b.images, b.prize_title FROM entries a, quiz b WHERE a.quiz_id = b.id AND a.member = 1 GROUP BY a.quiz_id ORDER BY a.time ASC
```

Comment: what column type is `time`? looks like varchar to me

Comment: Can you please build a schema in http://sqlfiddle.com/ ? So making us possible to debug and write a proper query ?

Comment: `time` column must be DOUBLE or FLOAT.

Comment: The output suggests that a.time is a text field thus MySQL sorts the records lexicographically.

Comment: I did change the column type to FLOAT, but getting same results.

Comment: You may need to convert the field to date using TO_DATE() before doing an order by. This might help you http://searchoracle.techtarget.com/tip/How-to-convert-milliseconds-to-the-proper-date-format

Comment: Well now it works without GROUP BY a.quiz_id, but i have to only output the best time from database, and not showing all other entries. for same quiz. It works with     SELECT DISTINCT a.quiz_id, a.time, b.images, b.prize_title FROM entries a, quiz b WHERE a.quiz_id = b.id AND a.member = 1  ORDER BY a.time ASC but not with     SELECT DISTINCT a.quiz_id, a.time, b.images, b.prize_title FROM entries a, quiz b WHERE a.quiz_id = b.id AND a.member = 1 GROUP BY a.quiz_id ORDER BY a.time ASC ....????

Answer (score 1):

If I see your statement(image) you are not using a.time but just 'time'. 'Time' is a type so you could try to put time within `` => `time`. Please see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/time.html for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Working example using a [DECIMAL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fixed-point-types.html) field for the timespan values.

```
<?php
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test;charset=utf8', 'localonly', 'localonly');
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
setup($pdo);


$q = '
    SELECT
        a.quiz_id, a.`time`
    FROM
        soFoo as a
    ORDER BY `time` ASC
';
foreach( $pdo->query($q, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $r) {
    echo join(', ', $r), "\r\n";
}


function setup($pdo) {
    $pdo->exec('
        CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE soFoo (
            id int auto_increment,
            quiz_id int,
            `time` Decimal(14,10),
            primary key (id)
        )
    ');

    $stmt = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO soFoo (quiz_id, `time`) VALUES (?,?)');
    $stmt->execute( array(3, '1.06445693970') );
    $stmt->execute( array(3, '1.85788297653') );
    $stmt->execute( array(1, '1298.33279896') );
    $stmt->execute( array(1, '24.8014650345') );
    $stmt->execute( array(1, '3.44685196877') );
    $stmt->execute( array(1, '33.5646929741') );
    $stmt->execute( array(1, '6.26836800575') );
    $stmt->execute( array(1, '7.55817890167') );
}
```

prints

```
3, 1.0644569397
3, 1.8578829765
1, 3.4468519688
1, 6.2683680058
1, 7.5581789017
1, 24.8014650345
1, 33.5646929741
1, 1298.3327989600
```